# .submit method doesn't work when trying to login

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to login to a web page to get some tables but my code doesn't work to login.

This is the inspect element for the login button

```
<a onclick="OpenWindowAndLogon();" id="lnkLogon" class="fltBtn" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;lnkLogon&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;default.aspx&quot;, false, true))">
                                                                                    <span>Login</span>
```

in here is my vba code.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject


Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.Navigate "https://www.teambinder.com/TeamBinder184/Logon/default.aspx"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document


With ieDoc.forms(0)
.txtUserId.Value = "8888"
.txtCompanyId.Value = "8888"
.txtPassword.Value = "88888"
```

'IN HERE WHERE IT DOES NOTHING WHILE SUPPOSE TO LOGIN TO THE PAGE'

```
`.submit`



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to manage the login process by targeting each element and the button by their ids.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Login()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.teambinder.com/TeamBinder184/Logon/default.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#txtUserId").Value = 8888
            .querySelector("#txtCompanyId").Value = 8888
            .querySelector("#txtPassword").Value = 8888
            .querySelector("#lnkLogon").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```